# Itext 7 - Vertical watermark using text

Tags: itext7

I have been trying to add a watermark in a pdf using Itext 7. The watermark needs to be at the left side of each page and should be vertical. Something like shown in the following image:

[image]

Instead of being in centre, it should be at the left side of the page.

I tried the following code, but any angle I try it does not work for me -

```
File mergedDoc = new File(mergedFileName + ".pdf"); 
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergedDoc));
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA));
Paragraph verticalWatermark = new Paragraph("My vertical watermark").setFont(font).setFontSize(30);

for (int i = 1 + pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i <= k; i++) {

      PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
      page.setIgnorePageRotationForContent(false);
      over = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(i));
      over.saveState();
      over.setExtGState(gs1);

      document.showTextAligned(verticalWatermark, 30f, 25f, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 90);

      over.restoreState();
      pdfDoc.close();
      document.close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please attach the image. You write *Something like shown in the attached image - "My Watermark (with text)"* but no image is attached. Also: where did you get your code?

Comment: The image is hidden behind the `1`. Edit your question to make the image inline so people don't have to follow external links.

Comment: Aha, thanks @AmedeeVanGasse I didn't see the image, but after you explained that it was hidden, it wasn't difficult for me to make it visible.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong in many places.

- You combine low-level operations such `saveState()`/`restoreState()` on a `PdfCanvas` in combination with the high-level `Document` class' `showTextAligned()` method.
- You start counting at `1 + pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages()` which is weird. Your code sample is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). No one but you can run it because no one but you knows what variables such as `k` and `gs1` are about. Not providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is often interpreted as *"I am asking a question, but I'm not interested in getting an answer."*
- You are defining a value in degrees where a value in radians is expected, see the API docs: [showTextAligned(Paragraph p, float x, float y, int pageNumber, TextAlignment textAlign, VerticalAlignment vertAlign, float radAngle)](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/RootElement.html#showTextAligned-com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph-float-float-int-com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment-com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment-float-)

I have taken the iText 7 Jump-Start Tutorial, and I have added a vertical watermark to the left of the page:

[image]

This was the code I used:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("My vertical watermark");
for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    document.showTextAligned(
        p, 36, 72, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM,
        (float)Math.PI / 2);
}
document.close();
```

As you can see: there's no need for a `PdfCanvas` and it's `Math.PI / 2` radians instead of `90` degrees.